# iOS xamarin web view not playing sound stream from website

Tags: c#, user-interface, web, view, uiwebview

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmY2I.png)

lines of code for the web view to display webpage on iOS app 
application runs but failed to produce the sound on the website play button stream

```
 public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        string url = "http://www.skyeradio.co.za";
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));

    }
```

Comment: please edit your code into the question

Comment: done thanks for responding